# In WEB API with EF6 models, how do I limit the length of a VARCHAR(MAX) column returned

Tags: c#, class, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, edmx

I have a user that will not be able to update their client this year.  One of my columns is VARCHAR(MAX) and their current client chokes on the field when it contains over 250 characters.  Since they are the only authorized client using this endpoint, I'd like to relieve their pain and just truncate the column at 250 characters. This is a read-only endpoint so I don't have to deal with updates.

I was thinking this would be a good place for partial classes - maybe could do this:

```
  public partial class Equipment_Detail
  {   
    public string note
    {
        get
        {
            return left(note, 250);
        }
        set { }
    }
  }
```

but it conflicts with the existing definition. I know I'm missing something very fundamental here but I only use .NET once a year.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The type '...Equipment_Detail' already contains a definition for 'note' - the auto-generated model has that field already. I just want to limit the size of the field upon return.

Comment: Why don't you return a DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTOs are a great idea but with all the `.Include()` in my controller (my model is quite complex at this point), I think I found a simpler solution :

1. rename the column in the designer from 'note' to 'fullnote' and make it private [image: Visual Studio properties screen shot]
2. in the partial class, create a note field and using the private fullnote, truncate if necessary:

   ```
   public string note
   {
       get
       {
           string _note = fullnote;
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_note))
           {
               if (_note.Length > 250)
               {
                   _note = _note.Substring(0, 250);
               }
           }
           return _note;
       }
       set { }
   }
   ```